# How to use "matching" field from one list to the same field in another list in designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a *library* which has a person field for each document. 
I have a **list** which has the same columns. When a document is added to my *library*, I want to update all items in my **list** with a line of text (the 'Path' column of the document) wherever the field in the **list** has the same info as the field in the *library*.

I attempted to test this by creating a workflow on my library which:

- Stores the author's name in the people picker field as a variable.
- Uses "Update Item in: **list**", matches the "Author" field of the item against the "Author" field in the document (the current item).
- Updates the "Title" field of the **list** item with the "Path"  field from the *library* document.

I have tried storing the author name as an integer (user id) as I've had to do with other look ups, but this isn't working. I believe the issue is not with setting a variable or setting the "field" value to the "path" of the document, but rather the issue is on how I'm matching the items.

The example below shows how I tried to match them but with "Author" in place of "Created By" and also with the variable containing the integer value from the look up. 
[image]

Comment: if this question is confusing, please let me know.